# Android - Determine whether a Service in my App is currently running?

Tags: android, service, android-service

**The Situation:**
- At a certain point, I will start a Service to show a "floating" foreground chathead/bubble.
- Later, I need to check whether or not this is currently "active", and if so, remove it..

**The Question:**
- How can I determine this, so I can decide whether or not it needs to be stopped?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

No need to determine if service is running. If you call stopService() it will stop the service if running. And if you are starting service again it will not start one more duplicate service.